# Unity WebGL Compression Formats

Tags: unity-game-engine, compression, webgl

In Unity, i created only one 3D hexagonal object and trying to build for WebGL.

I figured it out that if i change don't change **Player Settings>Publishing Settings>Compression Format** **Gzip** to **Disabled**, my project won't work on Chrome/Safari & Mozilla. Results are same with **Gzip** compression format. Why is that happen

Also this zero compression format give me about 15mb-20mb files so it takes too long to open on browsers. I need to reduces this time. I have only 28kb .fbx object in this project and 2 script.

Tested on localhost and these pages :

- [Web Link (Default-Uncompressed)](https://asmeyazilim.net/fenix2)
- [Alternative Web Server Link (itch.io)](https://320v.itch.io/fenixtest)

Any advice would be nice . Thanks.

Comment: For WebGL builds can get really big really fast. Make sure you are not making a development build, that makes it much worse. How are you hosting it?

Comment: `my project won't work on Chrome/Safari & Mozilla` I suspect this is more the way your server provides those

Comment: The compression shouldnt stop it working. Mine all work with and without on chrome etc safari works less well dur to it not supporting some apis as well as others do

Answer (score 1):

Solved. [As Unity Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-deploying.html) says, i need to configure web server side. But i don't know that yet so i clicked `Decompression Fallback` option to let unitygl to set that. I hope it helps others too. Because unity's default compression format is `Gzip` and `Decompression Fallback` is untick so it fails after build as default.

Comment: We had issues hosting on S3 until we set the content type on the uploaded files. CORS is a lot of fun too. Welcome to WebGL! :)

Comment: yeah same in IIS you have to explicitly remap the mimeTypes for all relevant unity files like e.g. `.unityweb`, `.bundle`, `.gz` (or `.br` accordingly),  -> `application/octet-stream` except for `.js.gz` -> `application/javascript` and `.wasm.gz` -> `application/wasm`